# Handling error messages in SCons using VariantDir

Tags: scons

When compiling a SConscript using `SConscript("src/SConscript", variant_dir=stage_dir)` all files encountered in the `SConscript` file is copied to the `stage_dir`. This is the behaviour I want.

But with the current setup of the compiler we end up with error messages that is like this:

```
g++ -o build\mingw_d\main.o
build\mingw_d\main.cpp: In function 'bool some_function()':
build\mingw_d\main.cpp:42:1: error: Some error message.
```

This points to the copied file (quite naturally since that is the file that is passed into the compiler).

This causes however our IDEs and editors to point to the wrong file to edit, as we want to edit the file in the `#/src/` folder.

I know there is a `duplicate=0` setting in the SConscript tool, but I believe that this is more of a workaround. Since `duplicate=1` is the default, I believe there is a practical way to achieve this.

Comment: It's not clear why you don't use duplicate=0?  It's not a workaround, it's an option.  In some cases tools aren't able to work without all files referenced being copied, so the default is duplicate=1 so those tools won't have an issue.  duplicate=0 is always going to be a little bit faster than duplicate=1 since it won't have to copy or symlink files.

Comment: It could very well be that duplicate=0 is the only practical solution. (Especially since you are an authority on the subject) But I in that case I am surprised duplicate is the default. The reason I was using duplicate was that it was the default choice, which led me to think that there was an easy way to to fix my problems with it. In that case I  will just try to solve the problem with duplicate.

Comment: It sounds like you thought using a non default option would be wrong?  If it was wrong, it wouldn't be an option at all..